# HTML, JQuery Инпут заполняется на основе выпадающего списка и кнопка становится активна, но только тогда, когда я введу символ

Tags: html, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста что нужно сделать, чтобы кнопка становилась активна от вставки сообщения из выпадающего списка?
Сейчас же я вставил сообщение из выпадающего списка и чтобы кнопка стала активной нужно ввести любой символ.
P.S. Далее я сделаю у input type="hidden"

```js
function checkParamsFilter() {
    var statusFilter = $('#statusFilter').val();

    if(statusFilter.length !== 0 ) {

        $('#submitFilter').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#submitFilter').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="statusFilter" onkeyup="checkParamsFilter()" name="filter" placeholder="Поиск по статусу заявки" />
                <select onchange=document.getElementById('statusFilter').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value>
                    <option disabled selected>Статус заявки</option>
                    <option value="Выполнено">Выполнено</option>
                    <option value="На выполнении">На выполнении</option>
                    <option value="Не выполнено">Не выполнено</option>
                </select>
                <div >
                    <button id="submitFilter" disabled type="submit">Найти</button>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select
  onchange="document.getElementById('statusFilter').value=this.value;checkParamsFilter();">
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!